# Reactjs Component lifecycle - Fetching data from user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to Reactjs. I try to build a filters system from a search result.
When user select a filter I would like get new data using an AJAX call according the chosen filter.

I set an eventHandler function on filter's checkbox which set state of my component. This make React re-render the component. But at this point, there is no newest data.

componentWillUpdate() seems perfect for this purpose but it will be deprecated on next release (17) unless using UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate().

How fetch newest data before re-rendering the component? Which lifecycle method is better choice?

First set of data is set on my `index.html` file

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Reactjs - Filtres component</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="filtres" class="filtres" style="width:250px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var filtres = [{
        "date": {
            "libelle": "Year",
            "buckets": {
                "date2018": {
                "name": "date[0]",
                "value": "2018",
                "title": 2018,
                "libelle": 2018,
                "nb": 1
             },
             "date2016": {
                "name": "date[1]",
                "value": "2016",
                "title": 2016,
                "libelle": 2016,
                "nb": 54
              },
              "date2015": {
                "name": "date[2]",
                "value": "2015",
                "title": 2015,
                "libelle": 2015,
                "nb": 70
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
         // some filters
        }
      }];
    </script>
    <script src="dist/filtresComponent.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

FiltresComponent.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Filtres from './Filtres'

ReactDOM.render(<Filtres filtres={filtres} />, document.getElementById('filtres'));
```

Filtres.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Filtres.css'

import Crit from './Crit'

class Filtres extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filtres : this.props.filtres,
      appliedFiltres : {}
    }
  }

  addFiltre = (filtreName, filtreValue) => {
    console.log('addFiltre from FiltresComponent !!');
    console.log('We add : ');
    console.log('filtreName :' + filtreName + ' ,value : ' + filtreValue);
    
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {appliedFiltres: Object.assign(state.appliedFiltres, {[filtreName]: filtreValue})}
    });

    console.log(this.state);
    
  }

  // before re-rendering sounds good but will be deprecated on reactjs 17
  componentWillUpdate = () => {
    console.log('componentWillUpdate');
    // Fetching before rendering ?
  }
  

  render() {
    console.log('render Filtres.js');
    return ([
      this.state.filtres.map((crit, index) =>  {
        let libelle = crit[Object.keys(crit)].libelle;
        let critValues = Object.values(crit[Object.keys(crit)].buckets);
        return <Crit key={index} libelle={libelle} critValues={critValues} addFiltre={this.addFiltre}/>
      })
    ])
  }
}

export default Filtres
```

Crit.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class Crit extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    open : true
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open : this.props.open
    }
  }

  showHideCrit = (e) => {
    if(this.state.open){
      e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
      this.setState({ open: false });
    }else{
      e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'flex';
      this.setState({ open: true });
    }
  }

  addFiltre = (e) => {
    console.log('addFiltre from CritComponent !!');
    // User chosen filter
    let filtreName = e.target.name;
    let filtreValue = e.target.value;
    // LiftUp
    this.props.addFiltre(filtreName, filtreValue);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render Crit.js');
    return ([
      <div className="crit">
        <a className={"js-head_crit " + (this.state.open ? 'open' : '' )+""} onClick={this.showHideCrit}>{this.props.libelle}</a>
        <div className="crit-values">
          {
            this.props.critValues.map((critValue,index) => {
              return (                
                  <div key={index} className="crit-value" data-count={critValue.nb}>
                      <input type="checkbox" name={critValue.name} value={critValue.value} onChange={this.addFiltre}/>
                      <label className="crit-libelle">
                          {critValue.libelle}
                          <span className="crit-nb">{critValue.nb}</span>
                      </label>
                  </div>                
              )
            })
          }
          </div>
      </div>
    ])
  }
}

export default Crit
```

Output

[image: Console output]

Here user want to filter by year : 2015
I add date[2] : 2015 to appliedFiltres using `this.setState`
Then I want to fetch data using the filter year = 2015
Finally re-render component with new values

Comment: So you basically want the act of selecting something to block until the data is fetched? That sounds like a bad user experience imo

Comment: I don't see what's bad... search tv screens, display result, then filters by brands (eg samsung, LG, philips), but maybe there is better way to achieve that using react, tell me :)

Comment: Yes. the bad thing is when people click on a checkbox they expect the checkbox to be checked instantly and not checked after some delay during which time the entire region becomes unresponsive for no obvious reason. Typically people will check > disable > show loader and then hide the loader and re-enable when data is loaded. This way users get feedback on what's going on

Comment: I don't expect that the checkbox will not be checked instantly..maybe my bad english is in cause ? ^^ I would like something like User check the checkbox > loader is showing up > display filtered result > hide loader, classic :)

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` works equally well for this. You can use the `prevProps` argument to check whether the update changed filters and then kick off the ajax request and set the loading state. The only difference is with `componentWillUpdate` is that this one runs after an update, however if you're going to be kicking off an async operation (like e.g. an ajax call) it doesn't matter because the async operation will not finish before the render anyway

Comment: **getDerivedStateFromProps** is other alternative.

Comment: that's what I do not understand.. I read on react blog that `componentDidUpdate` is designed to replace `componentWillUpdate` and I tried, but it's fired after re-rendering, and it takes prevProps as arg, but I use state, so how I should implement `componentDidUpdate` ?

Comment: @RajmaniArya Tried too, but not working ( but I'm sure that is not `getDerivedStateFromProps` the reason ;) )

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to trigger the fetch operation immediately after setting the new filters in the state, you can do this via a call back to `this.setState` method call:

```
  addFiltre = (filtreName, filtreValue) => {
    // ...other codes
    this.setState(
      {},  // state update value 
      this.fetchData() // The function to trigger the AJAX call
    );
  }
```

**Note**: The re-render should happen regardless of the triggered AJAX call, you shouldn't wait for the AJAX call to complete before doing the render because this would make you app un-usable(and miserable) for a while(until the AJAX call completes).

To ensure a good user experience and also avoid showing stale data, you can display maybe a loading component(which can be as simple as a text: `loading...`) while the fetch from sever is happening, for that you would need a state value to track the AJAX process. 
In the code block below, I added a `fetchingData` boolean to the state, you can use that to track when the data fetching is happening and when it is done.

```
class Filtres extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    // ...other codes
    this.state = {
      // ...other states
      fetchingData: false,
    };
  }

  // ...other methods

  fetchData() {
    // set fetchingData to true as soon as the AJAX process starts
    this.setState({ fetchingData: true });
    // make ajax call with set filters
    // when ajax call is done, set it back to false 
    this.setState({ fetchingData: false });
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.fetchingData) {
      // display loading component
    } else {
      // display the current data
    }

  // ...other methods
};
```